# How to restrict particular namespace docs to load in MarkLogic?

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic-10, xlink

I have huge number of data and in that I have .svg file format as well, which has `xlink` namespace, but a few of the svg doc do not have `xlink` namespace and these documents have to be skipped while loading into MarkLogic.

So, which function can I use to read the namespace to filter  or restrict while reading the data from file system.

I am using `xdmp:document-get("file path")` to read the doc from file system.

Sample xml with `xlink` NS -

```
<Books xmlns="http:books.com" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <book/>
</Books>
```

Sample xml without `xlink` NS -

```
<Books xmlns="http:books.com" >
  <book/>
</Books>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vlad Rose answer should work in most cases. However, it relies upon the instance document having the `xlink` namespace-prefix. It might not be `xlink`, but still be the xlink namespace-uri. For instance: `xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"`

You could instead use the `namespace::` axis and test if any of the namespaces have the `xlink` namespace-uri "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" like this:

```
let $doc := xdmp:document-get("file path")
return
  if (exists($doc//namespace::*[. eq "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"]))
  then xdmp:document-insert("/path/to/save/document.xml", $doc)
  else 
    (: Document does not have xlink namespace, skip this document :)
    ()
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped. But in MarkLogic 4 version when I am using xdmp:document-get("file path") for svg file without xlink namesapce it throws error "No Name Spcae binding". Could you please let me know what could be the reason for this error?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because that document you are trying to read is not well-formed XML. You can't use the `xlink` namespace-prefix if you don't declare the namespace. You could add the option to the `xdmp:document-get()` to repair: `<options xmlns="xdmp:document-get"><repair>full</repair></options>`

Comment: svg doc does not have xlink namespace, I am not using anywhere but still xdmp:doc-get throws error.

Comment: It may not be the xlink namespace, but some other namespace-prefix being used on content without defining what namespace it belongs to. Post the full error message and it would be helpful to post an example of the offending doc. The second XML in your question does not throw that error.